# Is the Careers site available on the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, ios-app

How can I view all jobs available on the Careers site?

A few days back I got a job link in my Stack Exchange application feed, and it seems it is available in the application, but I am not able to figure out how to open that.

Comment: What happens when you tap the feed item?

Comment: I was able to tap and then open as well Because that was available in feed, now I don't have jobs in feed I want to see open jobs. Don't know how I can open careers/job section from iOS app of stackexchange

Comment: No such thing yet, closed as dupe of similar feature request then.

Comment: You are right, I tried to search that if it is already asked but could not see tagged question. I thought it should be easy in comparison to what stackexchange app already have so its just me not able to find it in app.

Comment: Well, there might be a new official app sometime at 2017, customized to Stack Overflow, which means it will surely contain Jobs section. Stay tuned. ([source](https://stackapps.com/questions/7176/stack-overflow-iphone-app-placeholder).)